# Pretty version of Ruby's require statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, require

I've always thought this sort of thing ugly:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'hirb/config')
```

Is there a prettier alternative, maybe one written for Rails?

```
require_relative 'hirb/config'
require_relative '../another/file'
```

Comment: Ruby 1.9 has require_relative - though for the life of me I can't find its documentation or source right this moment. In any case, that might help once you find the source...

Comment: [Link to documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-require_relative) for Ruby 1.9’s `require_relative`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [extend the kernel](http://extensions.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Kernel.html).

```
module Kernel
    def require_relative(path)
      require File.join(File.dirname(caller[0]), path.to_str)
    end
end
```

Comment: ...but where do you require that?  ;-)

Comment: And why, exactly, isn't this native to Ruby itself?  It's not commonplace?

Answer (score 7):

The best approach is probably preparing your load path so you don't need to do all this. It's not especially difficult for your main module or init file to introduce a few other locations.

This is also affected by the RUBYLIB environment variable, as well as the -I command line parameter.

```
$: << File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'lib'), File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

Comment: caller[0] means you can abstract

Comment: You get this for free if your library is a gem (hint, hint).

Answer (score 6):

You could do

```
Dir.chdir(File.dirname(__FILE__) do
  require 'hirb/config'
  require '../another/file'
end
```

Whether or not that's better is a matter of taste, of course.

Comment: When code is ugly because of required but consistent cruft (e.g. the `File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), path)` stuff here), abstract abstract abstract!

Comment: I think this one isn't going to work out because __FILE__ is always relative to the file it is defined in, not the file it is called in.